# Fill array with range from different worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, range, worksheet

In a function I define my array like below but the function gives me #value when I use it in the worksheet. It works when I leave the part Worksheets("interestrates")., however, in the wrong sheet then. What can I do, to tell Excel to fill the array with values from the worksheet "interestrates"

array1 = Worksheets("interestrates").Range("a" & range1.Value & ":c" & range2.Value)

Comment: Can you please show the rest of the function? Also, please revise your question to correct some readability issues -- "when I leave the part `Worksheets("interestrates")`., however, in the wrong sheet then." <-- This doesn't make any sense. It is hard to tell what you're trying to say.

Comment: What I meant is that the function works perfectly fine if I assign the range ("a" & range1.Value & ":c" & range2.Value) to the array1. The problem then is that the array is then always filled with values of the range in the worksheet within which the function is used instead of the same range in the worksheet "interestrates". So for example if range1 = 1 and range2 = 50 the array is filled with values within A1:C50 of the worksheet "prices" (which is the worksheet I use the function in) as opposd to values that lie in A1:C50 in worksheet "interestrates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `range1` and `range2` are single cell Range objects which evaluate to an integer/long value, I believe this is your problem:

You have a multi-dimensional array (3 columns, and a varying number of rows to be determined by the maximum of `range1` or `range2`).  The number of rows doesn't really matter.  The problem is that you cannot put an array of values in a single cell.

Long story short, you should certainly be able to assign to an array like you are doing, for example:

[image]

**If your function is returning `#Value!` error, then there is some problem with the rest of your function, or with what you are expecting/attempting to do with the function.**

Comment: I did the same as you did, I said that Array1 needs to go from A:1 to C50 (assuming Range1=1 and Range2=50) but always in the worksheet "interestrates". When I enter the forumla as suggested by you, array1 always contains values of the worksheet I am currently using the function in. I need an addition that tells Excel: "Hi Excel, please make array1 a 50x3 array and fill it with the values from A1 to C50 of worksheet "interestrates" "

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, OK. I call this function from `Sheet2` and it displays results in the Locals window, values from the worksheet `Sheet1`.  This is what you expect. If you are not seeing the expected results in the Locals window, could you post some screenshots (upload to imgur.com if you are not able to provide them here)?

Comment: I found the issue: I am using a **German Excel** and so I needed to type **"Tabelle2"** instead of "Sheet2". Thank you very much for your help, it finally worked!